# Blank screen after publish to Expo

Tags: react-native, expo

my program was running correctly on my local machine. Why published project only shows a blank screen after it been pubilushed to the Expo server？

Comment: did  you publish app in development mode ?

Comment: Yes I have uploaded it to my expo account. It working correctly now.

Answer (score 1):

I have found an answer for this question. After npm install "uglify-es": "^3.2.2" and disable animation of TabNavigator by setting animationEnabled: false the problem been solved.

Comment: After upload application to expo. And running it on your own android device you may encounter undefined object exception. Try install uglify-es": "^3.2.2 to solve undefined object exception.